# App Crashing when adding media stream to peerconnection (WebRTC)

Tags: ios, webrtc

I am creating an iOS app with WebRTC calls. I am creating the RTCPeerConnection as below

```
RTCICEServer *iceServer = [[RTCICEServer alloc]
        initWithURI:[NSURL URLWithString:@"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]
           username:@""
           password:@""];    
    iceServers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [iceServers addObject:iceServer];
    [RTCPeerConnectionFactory initializeSSL];    
    RTCPeerConnectionFactory *peerConnectionFactory =
        [[RTCPeerConnectionFactory alloc] init];    
    RTCPeerConnection *peerConnection =
        [peerConnectionFactory peerConnectionWithICEServers:iceServers
                                                constraints:nil
                                                   delegate:self];
```

But, when I am trying to add a media stream to this connection, the app crashes with no proper logs. I have tried with different publicly available STUN/TURN servers, but same result. I guess the problem is with ICE. Any help on this please? :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed. I was declaring the RTCPeerConnectionFactory and RTCPeerConnection objects as local variables. They were getting deallocated before the delegate methods were called. I made them instance variables and it's fixed.

Comment: I was running into a crash, and it was also due to my `RTCPeerConnectionFactory` local variable getting deallocated. This fixed my problem, thanks!